# Need a suggestion in Speech Recognition?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I developed an application which converts from voice to text using `SAPI 5.1`.

As the accuracy is too weak, I decided to create my own grammar, I created my own grammmar which  only recognizes numbers from  one to ten.

I failed in accuracy again. So I went in deep with the grammar file. I went through Lexion File which is used for pronunciation. So my question is

1. will lexicon file improve the
   accuracy? so that I can use
   pronunciation of numbers one to ten
   in the Lexicon file and then
   use it.
2. I need a template on how
       to create a lexicon file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your speech recognition accuracy is weak, it could be any one of the following reasons:

1. Not enough training data - note that creating a speaker-dependant speech recognition system (that is tied to only one speaker) requires a large number of units of each of the words (one to ten in your case). Individual units are required for training initial models with and then embedded training data maybe required to further improve the models.
2. A speaker-independent speech recognition model will require even more data.
3. There is a mismatch between the testing and training data. If the models were created using noise-less data or on data with an accent, it may be difficult to get good results when testing with data that has a lot of noise or has a different accent.

But more details about the speech recognition system you are trying to build would be better.

Update 1: Since you mention in the comments that you are using Microsoft Speech SDK, here is a guide to [training the speech SDK on sounds/accents](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306901). Just follow the instructions and that should set you on your way.

Comment: Hi Sriram , So what u r saying is to train the data.Yes my scenario is " speaker-independent speech recognition model" , but i didnt get you in these words "will require even more data"?. "Individual units are required for training initial models " , so what u r saying is to go control panel speech and train the engine multiple times..is this right?

Comment: @Bhuvan: If you want a speaker-independent speech recogniser, then the requirements for data are greater than for a speaker-dependent one. I am not sure what speech recognition software you are using, so it will be difficult for me to comment on how you should train. Training the engine for the specific requirements of your system (say American English) is a good option. It is possible that it may not be needed, but for that you will have to refer to the docs of the speech recognition system.

Comment: :- thanks for the info.I am using Microsoft speech SDK 5.1, i developed app using C#,yeah i referred many docs of this, but they are not fully explained. My question is how do we train an engine , to make it as speaker independent speech recognizer? I need a hint to make my engine that flexible , so that it has to recognize atleast numbers. will u shortly explain how do we train the engine? May be i missed the core one i.e., "train the engine perfectly"

Comment: :- Thanks a lot. i will do this once, if this makes my engine as speaker independent(atleast dependent) speech recognizer, then i m done. Thank you, if i need any help ,i will message here. should i concern about US and UK English for numbers (upto 9)

Comment: @Bhuvan: If you are building a system for Indian english, then no. If you are building a system for US and UK English, then yes.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, an upvote or mark-this-answer-as-correct would be nice.

Comment: ok i am building system for Indian English (numbers upto 1 to 9) , so what are the points i need to concern?

Comment: Hi Sriram.. I got a problem with lexicon file. i created lexeme file which contains grapheme and lexeme of numbers from 1 to 10. but when i try to compile it in grammar compiler , it states the lexeme tag as invalid tag. How to avoid this?